# MySQL join, I need some expert openion

Tags: mysql

friends i have two tables ie 'orders' and 'users' as bellow:

Table data for `user`

```
id  |   user_name
7   |   ab
8   |   hb
9   |   OR
```

Table data for `orders`

```
order_id    | user_id   | assign_date|description | other
    1       |    8      | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    2       |    9      | 2015-10-03 |test abc.   | NULL
    3       |    9      | 2015-10-03 |test d.     | NULL
    4       |    7      | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    5       |    8      | 2015-10-03 |test abc.   | NULL
    6       |    8      | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    7       |    7      | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    8       |    9      | 2015-10-03 |test da.    | NULL
    9       |    8      | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
```

Im looking for the output like this (heading as user ids and list of order numbers in the concerned user_id column)

```
user_id7    | user_id8  | user_id9  |
    4       |    1      |    2      |
    7       |    5      |    3      |
            |    6      |    8      |
            |    9      |
```

[image]

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
    And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <!--Table `user`-->

id | user_name
7 | ab
8 | hb



<!--Table `orders`-->

order_id | user_id | assign_date|description | other
    1  |    8    | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    2  |    7    | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    3  |    8    | 2015-10-03 |test abc.   | NULL
    4  |    8    | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    5  |    7    | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
    6  |    8    | 2015-10-03 |test desc.  | NULL
============================================

required output
| user_id7 | user_id8 | 
|    2  |    1    | 
|    5  |    3    | 
|      |    4    | 
|      |    6    |

Comment: Edit the question with your code, don't reply here with code. Reply here only if you're commenting on a comment.